# Opening contacts and aquiring phone number

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to open my contacts inside my app and allow the user to choose a contact, then the user will be able to choose the phone number they want to use. Right now the method I have allows me to select the proper contact and phone number, however I don't know how to tell the user if the phone number is a home phone number, or cell phone number.

How do I mention next to the number if it is a cell, home, work ,etc

This is what I'm using now to get the phone number from the contacts. Thanks![image]

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();

            try {

                String id = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
                Cursor phoneCur = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                final ArrayList<String> phonesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (phoneCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several phone addresses
                    // if the phone addresses were stored in an array
                    String phone = phoneCur
                            .getString(phoneCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
                    phonesList.add(phone);
                }
                phoneCur.close();
                if (phonesList.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Phone Number in Contact",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (phonesList.size() == 1) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                    case (1):
                        edit1.setText(phonesList.get(0));
                        break;
                    case (2):
                        edit2.setText(phonesList.get(0));
                        break;
                    case (3):
                        edit3.setText(phonesList.get(0));
                        break;
                    }
                } else {

                    final String[] phonesArr = new String[phonesList.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < phonesList.size(); i++) {
                        phonesArr[i] = phonesList.get(i);
                    }

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Settings.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("Choose Phone Number");
                    ((Builder) dialog).setItems(phonesArr,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    String selectedEmail = phonesArr[which];
                                    switch (requestCode) {
                                    case (1):
                                        edit1.setText(selectedEmail);
                                        break;
                                    case (2):
                                        edit2.setText(selectedEmail);
                                        break;
                                    case (3):
                                        edit3.setText(selectedEmail);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }).create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("FILES", "Failed to get phone data", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "="
            + contactId, null, null + " DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        int phoneNumberColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        int phoneTypecolumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

        int phoneType = Integer.parseInt(cursor
            .getString(phoneTypecolumn));

        String phoneNumberType = "";

        if (phoneType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME) {
            phoneNumberType = "Home";
        } else if (phoneType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            phoneNumberType = "Mobile";
        } .....//Similarly the other types could be obtained.

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Hope this would help.